# How to automatically change a image with one downloaded from the web?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have to create a gallery with downloaded images and I want to show a loading image while I'm downloading them.
I use this adapter:

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
public ImageView imageView;
private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
private int imageWidth;

public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filePaths,
    int imageWidth,Context context1) {

this._activity = activity;
this._filePaths = filePaths;
this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
this.context=context1;
```

}

```
public int getCount() {
    return this._filePaths.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this._filePaths.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    } 


    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gallery_image);

   imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
   imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,imageWidth));
  Log.e("Position",position+"");
 new RetreiveBitMap().execute(_filePaths.get(position));

return imageView;
 }

class RetreiveBitMap extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Bitmap> {

private Exception exception;
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

    Bitmap bm = null;
    URL myFileUrl =null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 1;
    try {
        myFileUrl= new URL(urls[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {

        String encodedfilename = Base64.encodeToString(urls[0].getBytes(),0);

    //Controllo presenza della cache
    try {
    InputStream check = context.openFileInput(encodedfilename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Se non presente, scarico il file

    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
     //Salvataggio cache
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(encodedfilename,    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len1 = 0;
    while ( (len1 = is.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
    fos.write(buffer,0, len1);
    }

    fos.close();
    }

     bm =     BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.openFileInput(encodedfilename),null,options);


    } catch (IOException e) {
Log.e("errore download",e.getMessage());
    } 
    return bm;

} 
protected void onPreExecute() {

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.spinner);
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap imageBit) {

    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBit);
  }
 }
}
```

With this code only the last image in the view change into the downloaded image.
The image that appears should be the first of the grid and not the last!

Comment: I just did that using Picasso (by Square) and it took minutes to implement. There are at least two more free libraries available for Android which do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is some variation of a "lazy loader" that will load content as it is downloaded. Accomplishing this in a `GridView` or `ListView` is not always that obvious as one would think because of the built view recycling optimizations present in both view types. There are a few ways to approach this.

(1) Update add a field to each `Object` contained in the `Collection` backing your adapter that holds an image url. Load a default image initially and, when the url is known, update the field in the `Object` and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the view to update.

(2) Implement an outside image cache that images are downloaded too. Start displaying the view with a defalt image. When the downloads are complete, notifyDataSetChanged. Check for the new images in your getView method and update. For example - using an `LruCache` (google how to set this up)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null){
        v = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout_for_view, null);
    }

    ImageView picture = v.findViewById(R.id.picture_view);
    Bitmap b = memCache.get(KEY_VALUE);
    if(b != null){
        pictureView.setImageBitmap(b);
    } else {
        picture.setImageBitmap(memCache.get(DEFAULT_IMAGE_KEY);
        if(!checkedKeyList.contains(KEY_VALUE){
            downloadPictureAndAddToCache(KEY_VALYE);
            checkedKeyList.add(KEY_VALYE);
    }

}
```

You will notice the example above is semi-psudeo code. There are methods in there that are not defined. That is because I do not know the structure of the objects you are trying to downlaod images for. The general idea, however, is to check the external cache. If an image is contained for that object (as located by some unique key you define) then use that image. If no image is found, try to download that image using your `AsyncTask`. I added a `List<T>` that would represent a collection of keys that you checked. This is to prevent an infinate loop in the event that a picture is not found or does not exist for one of the key values. In each case, when the picture is done being downloaded, call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter to refresh the views. You can do this onPostExecute from within your `AsyncTask`.